# How to remove "Unresolved refernce" errror in PyCharm I have changed python interpreter so many times but not working

Tags: python, html, django, pycharm, django-apps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZXSH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OBQR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wup9O.png)

Guys please help me what should I do? I tried so many times to change the Python Interpreter path also I have reinstalled my python and pycharm but this error is not resolving please help me :(

Comment: @THUNDER07 I am not working in virtual enviroment

Comment: verify that module is installed correctly.

Comment: @D.L I run command python manage.py startapp searchapp but not working :(

Comment: Did you tried this `from models import Services`?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `searchapp` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py`?

You should probably add

```
'searchapp.apps.SearchappConfig',
```

into `INSTALLED_APPS`, like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'searchapp.apps.SearchappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```